# css to javascript for mozilla firefox extension

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, mozilla

I want this CSS code in javascript for my borderify.js file for a mozilla firefox extension. 
This extension is for youtube.com to hide the recommendation box on the right of the videos i did this with:

```
document.getElementById("related").style.display = "none";
```

but i want also center the video and comment box:

```
.ytd-watch.ytd-watch{
margin: auto;
}
```

i searched and tryed in the console like 3 hours straight and didnt figured out how to convert this css to javascript.

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName("ytd-watch ytd-watch").style.margin="auto";

document.getElementsByClassName("ytd-watch ytd-watch").style.margin="auto";

document.getElementsByClassName("ytd-watch ytd-watch").style.marginAuto;

document.querySelectorAll(".ytd-watch").style.margin = "auto";
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` ?

Comment: What you mean by that?